# What is the origin story of the Santa character in Violent Night?

Tags: plot-explanation, violent-night

In the 2022 comedic and violent action, christmas movie [Violent Night](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt12003946/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) a real but disillusioned Santa character gets involved in saving a family from a bunch of violent robbers.

At the start of the movie he is in a bar, drunk, claiming to be the "real" santa while talking to other (fake santa) characters. He is also moaning that today's kids are unbearable and he doesn't really want to do this role and more ant this might be the last year he does it. we soon realise that he is the real Santa Claus and has some magical powers (he has a flying sleigh pulled by reindeer).

While delivering presents to a rich family, a violent robbery starts and, while initially unwilling to do anything, he is persuaded by various events and the young daughter that he should. He tells a somewhat opaque story about how he was once a violent warrior and is persuades by the daughter that his old skills might help save the family. Comedic and refreshingly gory violence ensues.

But what is his origin story as the real Santa? How did he go from being what looks like a nasty viking raider to being the Santa who rewards kids who have been good with presents? Where did his magical powers come from? (in short, what did I miss?)

Comment: As part of your 'xmas/pagan' cultural education, you need to read [or even watch, though I'd go for read] Terry Pratchett's Hogfather. It has pretty much the whole tale, couched in 'not our world' naming conventions. [I haven't seen this movie, so idk how closely it adheres to the 'true' mythology.]

Comment: @Tetsujin While Hogfather is a great read and other origin stories for Santa are helpful, I'm looking for the specific in-universe version here.

Comment: some say that Santa Claus shares [many similarities](https://sonsofvikings.com/blogs/history/viking-origins-of-christmas-yule-traditions) with Odin, so a viking warrior wouldn't be a true surprise?